# Open a dialog from a custom adapter

Tags: android

I have a custom adapter for a listview whose cells contain a delete button.
I want to display a message "really delete this entry?" when delete is pressed.

I handle the delete button event from the inside of the custom adapter, problem is that in order to create a dialog I need a reference to the current activity...how can I solve this?
Just using the context leads me to a null pointer exception.

Comment: did u send your activity context to the adapter constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This should be the skeleton of your adapter so that activity is able to pass the context forward to your adapter..**

```
public class ImagePrepare extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;

        public ImagePrepare(Context ctx, String[] icons,DisplayMetrics m) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.ctx=ctx;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return lengthofdata;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Put this code...

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder((Activity) v.getContext());

            alertDialog.setTitle("Delete this item?");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);

            alertDialog.setPositiveButton(
                "Delete",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Do the stuff..
                        }
                    }
                );


            }

            alertDialog.show();
```

on your listview click listener:

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {

}
```

Is what you were looking for?

Comment: its getting Error.

Comment: its getting crash : java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this.

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                LayoutInflater layout = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View popupView = layout.inflate(R.layout.popup1, null);
                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                int height = display.getHeight();
                int width = display.getWidth();
                final PopupWindow popupWindaow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                        (int) (width / 1.4), (int) (height / 2.5));
                popupWindaow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

                TextView tv1 = (TextView) popupView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView1);                                  

                tv1.setText("Really delete this entry?");

                Button No = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.No);
                            Button Yes = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.Yes);
                Yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        //code to delete

                    }
                });

                No.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        popupWindaow.dismiss();

                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

I hope this will help you.